# How to integrate a RESTfull API with php and mySQL database

Tags: php, api, rest

I'm doing a project for school where I need to use a RESTfull API, made by me. The project consists in a website to purchase items and more, however, for simplicity purposes I'm just going to ask for help with the signup page.

First I want to clarify how my project is organised:

I have a directory with the html and form for the signup (signup.php) and inside that directory I have a "includes" one where I have the db connection file (dbh.inc.php) and the signup php code (signup.inc.php). I also have the API I want to use in the main folder

So it would be:

1. main/signup.php
2. main/includes/dbh.inc.php
3. main/includes/signup.inc.php
4. main/myAPI.yaml

main/signup.php:

```
//some code above

<form action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="post">
                <label for="NIF">NIF:</label>
                <input type="text" name="NIF" placeholder="NIF" required>

                <label for="nome">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="User Name" required>

                <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required>

                <label for="telemovel">telemóvel:</label>
                <input type="text" name="telemovel" placeholder="987654321" required>

                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password" required>
            
                <label for="password">Repeat Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="pwd-repeat" placeholder="Repeat Password" required>

                <button type="submit" name="signup-submit">Register</button>
            </form>

//som code bellow
```

main/includes/dbh.inc.php

```
$servername = "localhost";
$dBUsername = "root";
$dBPassword = "";
$dBName = "impacto_encomendas";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dBUsername, $dBPassword, $dBName);
        if (!$conn) {
          die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
```

main/includes/signup.inc.php:

```
if (isset($_POST['signup-submit'])){
    require 'dbh.inc.php';

    $nif = $_POST['NIF'];
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $telemovel = $_POST['telemovel'];
    $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
    $pwdRepeat = $_POST['pwd-repeat'];

    //Check for errors

    if (empty($nome) || empty($nif) || empty($telemovel) || empty($email) || empty($pwd)|| empty($pwdRepeat)){ //Check for empty values
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=emptyFields&uid=".$nome."&mail=".$email);
        exit();

    } else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $nome)) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invalidmailuid"); //n enviamos nada porque nada esta corretamente inputed
        exit();

    } else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { //Check for valid email format
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invalidmail&uid=".$nome);
        exit();

    } else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $nome)) { //Check for valid characters
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invaliduid&mail=".$email);
        exit();

    } else if ($pwd !== $pwdRepeat){
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=passwordcheck&uid=".$nome."&mail=".$email);
        exit();
    } else { // NIF taken

        $nif = intval($nif);
        $sql = "SELECT nif FROM utilizador WHERE nif=?"; //Prepared statements for code injection prevention
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){

            header("Location: ../signup.php?error=sqlerror");
            exit();
        } else {

            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $nif); //String -> s; Int -> i; Blob -> b; Double -> d (tantos caracteres como placeholders)
            mysqli_execute($stmt);
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
            $resultCheck = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);

            if ($resultCheck > 0){
                header("Location: ../signup.php?error=niftaken&mail=".$email);
                exit();

            // no errors (register)    
            } else {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO utilizador (nif, nome, email, telemovel, password) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
                $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
                    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=sqlerror");
                    exit();
                } else { //Insert in DB
                    $hashedPwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);//hash password

                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "issss", $nif, $nome, $email, $telemovel, $hashedPwd);
                    try{ //bad coding. only exception left is not unique key (email-telemovel)
                        mysqli_execute($stmt);
                        header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=success");
                        exit();
                    }catch (Exception $e){
                        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=notUnique&mail=".$email);
                        exit();
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
    } //end of else
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    mysqli_close($conn);

} else { //if users accesses the page some how not in the proper way
    header("Location: ../signup.php");
    exit();
}
```

All of this code is working correctly without the usage of the myAPI.yaml. Now, my main objective, like I mentioned before, is to integrate it in the signup.inc.php and I have no idea how to do it. Here is the code of the API (for this question you only need to read the /utilizadores path:

main/myAPI.yaml:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Community Local Support API Rest
  description: 
    An example of a preliminar API Rest as part of a FCUL project, made with Swagger editor. 
  version: 1.0.12

  contact:
    email: fc54961@alunos.fc.ul.pt

externalDocs:
  description: Find out more about Swagger
  url: http://swagger.io

paths:
#----------------------------------Utilizadores----------------------------------
  /utilizadores:
    get:
      summary: Get all users
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: nome
          schema:
            type: string
          description: Filter by name
        - in: query
          name: email
          schema:
            type: string
          description: Filter by email
        - in: query
          name: telemovel
          schema:
            type: string
          description: Filter by phone number
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A list of users
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Utilizador'
    post:
      summary: Create a new user
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Utilizador'
      responses:
        '201':
          description: User created
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Utilizador'

  /utilizadores/{userId}:
    get:
      summary: Get a user by ID
      parameters:
        - name: userId
          in: path
          required: true
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int64
      responses:
        '200':
          description: The requested user
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Utilizador'
        '404':
          description: User not found

    put:
      summary: Update a user by ID
      parameters:
        - name: userId
          in: path
          required: true
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int64
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/UtilizadorUpdate'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: User updated
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Utilizador'
        '404':
          description: User not found

    delete:
      summary: Delete a user by ID
      parameters:
        - name: userId
          in: path
          required: true
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int64
      responses:
        '204':
          description: User deleted
        '404':
          description: User not found

  /utilizadores/login:
    post:
      summary: Login with email and password
      requestBody:
        description: User email and password
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                email:
                  type: string
                  format: email
                  description: The user's email address
                password:
                  type: string
                  description: The user's password
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Login successful
        '401':
          description: Unauthorized
#------------------------------------Produtos------------------------------------
  /produtos:
    get:
      summary: Get all products
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: nome
          schema:
            type: string
          description: Filter by name
        - in: query
          name: dataproducao
          schema:
            type: string
            format: date
          description: Filter by production date
        - in: query
          name: price
          schema:
            type: number
          description: Filter by price
        - in: query
          name: categoria
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Categoria'
          description: Filter by category
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A list of all products
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Produto'
    post:
      summary: Create a new product
      requestBody:
        description: The product to create
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/ProdutoNew'
      responses:
        '201':
          description: The created product
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Produto'

  /produtos/{productId}:
    get:
      summary: Get a product by ID
      parameters:
        - name: productId
          in: path
          required: true
          description: The ID of the product to retrieve
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int64
      responses:
        '200':
          description: The product
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Produto'
        '404':
          description: Product not found

    put:
      summary: Update a product by ID
      parameters:
        - name: productId
          in: path
          required: true
          description: The ID of the product to update
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int64
      requestBody:
        description: The updated product
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Produto'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: The updated product
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Produto'
        '404':
          description: Product not found

    delete:
      summary: Delete a product by ID
      parameters:
        - name: productId
          in: path
          required: true
          description: The ID of the product to delete
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int64
      responses:
        '204':
          description: Product deleted
        '404':
          description: Product not found

  /produtos/search:
    get:
      summary: Search for products
      parameters:
        - name: nome
          in: query
          description: The name of the product to search for
          schema:
            type: string
        - name: dataproducao
          in: query
          description: The production date of the product to search for
          schema:
            type: string
            format: date
        - name: preco
          in: query
          description: The price of the product to search for
          schema:
            type: number
        - name: categoria
          in: query
          description: The category of the product to search for
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A list of matching products
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Produto'
#-----------------------------------Categorias-----------------------------------
  /categorias:
    get:
      summary: Get all categories
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A list of categories
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Categoria'
    post:
      summary: Create a new category
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/CategoriaNew'
      responses:
        '201':
          description: User created
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Categoria'
  /categorias/{categoriaId}:
    get:
      summary: Get a category by ID
      parameters:
        - name: categoriaId
          in: path
          required: true
          description: The ID of the category to retrieve
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int64
      responses:
        '200':
          description: The category
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Categoria'
#-----------------------------------Transportes----------------------------------
  /transportes:
    get:
      summary: Get all transports
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: unidade_producao
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int64
          description: Filter by production unit
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A list of all transports
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Transporte'
    post:
      summary: Create a new transport
      requestBody:
        description: The transport to create
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Transporte'
      responses:
        '201':
          description: The created transport
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Transporte'

  /transportes/{matricula}:
    get:
      summary: Get a transport by license plate
      parameters:
        - name: matricula
          in: path
          required: true
          description: The license plate of the transport to retrieve
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: The transport
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Transporte'
        '404':
          description: Transport not found

    put:
      summary: Update a transport by license plate
      parameters:
        - name: matricula
          in: path
          required: true
          description: The license plate of the transport to retrieve
          schema:
            type: string
      requestBody:
        description: The updated transport
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Transporte'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: The updated transport
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Transporte'
        '404':
          description: Transport not found

    delete:
      summary: Delete a transport by license plate
      parameters:
        - name: matricula
          in: path
          required: true
          description: The license plate of the transport to retrieve
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        '204':
          description: Transport deleted
        '404':
          description: Transport not found
#--------------------------------Unidade Producao--------------------------------
  /unidadeproducao:
    get:
      summary: Get all production units
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: fornecedor
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int64
          description: Filter by supplier
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A list of all production units
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/UnidadeProducao'
    post:
      summary: Create a new production unit
      requestBody:
        description: The production unit to create
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/UnidadeProducao'
      responses:
        '201':
          description: The created production unit
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/UnidadeProducaoNew'

  /unidadeproducao/{unidadeproducaoid}:
    get:
      summary: Get a production unit by ID
      parameters:
        - name: unidadeproducaoid
          in: path
          required: true
          description: The ID of the production unit to retrieve
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int64
      responses:
        '200':
          description: The production unit
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/UnidadeProducao'
        '404':
          description: Production unit not found

    put:
      summary: Update a production unit by ID
      parameters:
        - name: unidadeproducaoid
          in: path
          required: true
          description: The ID of the production unit to retrieve
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int64
      requestBody:
        description: The updated production unit
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/UnidadeProducaoNew'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: The updated production unit
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/UnidadeProducao'
        '404':
          description: Production unit not found

    delete:
      summary: Delete a production unit by ID
      parameters:
        - name: unidadeproducaoid
          in: path
          required: true
          description: The ID of the production unit to retrieve
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int64
      responses:
        '204':
          description: Production unit deleted
        '404':
          description: Production unit not found
#-----------------------------------Encomendas-----------------------------------
  /encomendas:
    get:
      summary: Get all orders
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: consumidor
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int64
          description: Filter by consumer
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A list of all orders
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Encomenda'
    post:
      summary: Create a new order
      requestBody:
        description: The order to create
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/EncomendaNew'
      responses:
        '201':
          description: The created order
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Encomenda'

  /encomendas/{encomendaid}:
    get:
      summary: Get an order by ID
      parameters:
        - name: encomendaid
          in: path
          required: true
          description: The ID of the order to retrieve
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int64
      responses:
        '200':
          description: The order
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Encomenda'
        '404':
          description: Order not found
    delete:
      summary: Delete an order by ID
      parameters:
        - name: encomendaid
          in: path
          required: true
          description: The ID of the order to retrieve
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int64
      responses:
        '204':
          description: Order deleted
        '404':
          description: Order not found

components:
  securitySchemes:
    BasicAuth:
      type: http
      scheme: basic
  schemas:
    Utilizador:
      type: object
      required:
        - nif
        - nome
        - email
        - telemovel
        - password
      properties:
        nif:
          type: integer
          format: int64
          description: The user ID
        nome:
          type: string
          description: The name of the user
        email:
          type: string
          format: email
          description: The user's email address
        telemovel:
          type: string
          description: The user's phone number
        password:
          type: string
          description: The user's password
    UtilizadorUpdate:
      type: object
      required:
        - nome
        - email
        - telemovel
        - password
      properties:
        nome:
          type: string
          description: The name of the user
        email:
          type: string
          format: email
          description: The user's email address
        telemovel:
          type: string
          description: The user's phone number
        password:
          type: string
          description: The user's password
    Produto:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        nome:
          type: string
        dataproducao:
          type: string
          format: date
        preco:
          type: number
        categoria:
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Categoria'
    ProdutoNew:
      type: object
      properties:
        nome:
          type: string
        dataproducao:
          type: string
          format: date
        preco:
          type: number
        categoria:
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Categoria'
    Categoria:
      type: object
      required:
        - id
        - nome
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          format: int64
          description: The category ID
        nome:
          type: string
          description: The name of the category
    CategoriaNew:
      type: object
      required:
        - nome
      properties:
        nome:
          type: string
          description: The name of the category
    Transporte:
      type: object
      required:
        - matricula
        - capacidade
        - quantidade
      properties:
        matricula:
          type: string
          description: The transport's license plate
        capacidade:
          type: integer
          format: int64
          description: The maximum capacity of the transport
        quantidade:
          type: integer
          format: int64
          description: The capacity at which the transport is currently at
        unidade_producao:
          type: integer
          format: int64
          description: The production unit that the transport is connected to
    UnidadeProducao:
      type: object
      required:
        - unidadeproducaoid
        - fornecedor
        - morada
        - xcord
        - ycord
        - transportes
      properties:
        unidadeproducaoid:
          type: integer
          format: int64
          description: The production unit's ID
        fornecedor:
          type: integer
          format: int64
          description: The supplier's ID
        morada:
          type: string
          description: The production unit's address
        xcord:
          type: number
          description: The production unit's address' longitude
        ycord:
          type: number
          description: The production unit's address' latitude
        transportes:
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Transporte'
          description: The transports associated with the production unit
    UnidadeProducaoNew:
      type: object
      required:
        - fornecedor
        - morada
        - xcord
        - ycord
      properties:
        fornecedor:
          type: integer
          format: int64
          description: The supplier's ID
        morada:
          type: string
          description: The production unit's address
        xcord:
          type: number
          description: The production unit's address' longitude
        ycord:
          type: number
          description: The production unit's address' latitude
        transportes:
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Transporte'
          description: The transports associated with the production unit
    Encomenda:
      type: object
      required:
        - encomendaid
        - consumidor
        - data_encomenda
        - preco_total
        - quantidade_total
        - produtos
      properties:
        encomendaid:
          type: integer
          format: int64
          description: The order's ID
        consumidor:
          type: integer
          format: int64
          description: The consumer's ID
        data_encomenda:
          type: string
          format: date
          description: The order's date
        preco_total:
          type: number
          description: The order's total price
        quantidade_total:
          type: number
          description: The order's total item quantity
        produtos:
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Produto'
          description: Products associated with the order
    EncomendaNew:
      type: object
      required:
        - consumidor
        - data_encomenda
        - preco_total
        - quantidade_total
        - produtos
      properties:
        consumidor:
          type: integer
          format: int64
          description: The consumer's ID
        data_encomenda:
          type: string
          format: date
          description: The order's date
        preco_total:
          type: number
          description: The order's total price
        quantidade_total:
          type: number
          description: The order's total item quantity
        produtos:
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Produto'
          description: Products associated with the order

security:
  - BasicAuth: []
```

Also, I think it is important to mention that my "utilizador" table in my sql database has the following structure:

```
TABLE `utilizador` (
  `nif` int(9) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `telemovel` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `password` LONGTEXT NOT NULL)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`nif`),
 ADD UNIQUE KEY `telemovel_email` (`telemovel`,`email`) USING BTREE;
```

All of this is running locally using Xampp. To sum up the **question** is: **what do I change in my code in order to include the API in the project?**